# Difference between Data Storage and Hosting Storage?

Tags: firebase

In the Firebase 'Pricing & Plans' for the free Hacker Plan, it says we have "100MB Data Storage" and "1GB Hosting Storage" but what exactly is the difference between data and hosting storage?

By extension, is there a difference between Data and Host transfers which are also mentioned in the plan description?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Firebase is an online JSON database that synchronizes changes in realtime. Any data you store in that JSON database, counts against that data storage limit. Any data written to or read from the JSON database, counts against the data transfer limit.

Firebase also offers a hosting solution, where you can store static resources, such as HTML, JavaScript and CSS. Any files stored on Firebase's hosting servers, count against the hosting storage limit. Any time those files are updated or served to a visitor, counts against the hosting transfer limit.

By putting static files on Firebase hosting, you can build an entire dynamic web application, without requiring your own server.

See the [documentation on Firebase's JavaScript API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/), which is the API you'd use to access the data storage; and the [features of Firebase's hosting](https://www.firebase.com/hosting.html), which is what you'd use to [update the hosted files](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/quickstart.html).