# How to fix Firebase storage error?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

so I am trying to use the Firebase storage, and when I copied and pasted these lines of code in dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'
```

I get a build error that states:

Error:(33, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.2.0
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog

AND

Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0
Open File
Show in Project Structure dialog

and

Error:(34, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog

Here is what my dependencies look like.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Also, what is the difference between Firebase database and firebase storage? when would you use one over the other, dont they both store information for you?

Comment: I think the `com.firebase:` beginning dependencies are deprecated now that Google owns firebase (compare the last two dependencies). Because they are above the latest ones, it may cause an error. Database is a database - you can store primitive data types there. The storage is more like a "cloud" - you can upload images, media, etc.

Comment: Do you have the Google Play Services installed in the SDK Manager?

Comment: @LordRaydenMK Yeah i do, but maybe i need to update them? is that the only possible solution?

Comment: On where to store what kind of data, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482907/firebase-differences-between-realtime-database-and-file-storage/37483948#37483948

Comment: @LordRaydenMK I updated my SDK manager, but still no luck :/ I can't seem to use Firebase database...

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed [our getting started instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)? It's possible that you're missing the plugin that helps resolve these deps.

You're also going to want to remove the lines:

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.3.1'
```

and replace them with the upgraded versions:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.2'
```

As for the difference between Firebase Database and Firebase Storage, the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/#implementation_path) says this:

> - The Firebase Realtime Database stores JSON application data, like game state or chat messages, and synchronizes changes instantly across all connected devices.
> - Firebase Remote Config stores developer-specified key-value pairs to change the behavior and appearance of your app without requiring users to download an update.
> - Firebase Hosting hosts the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript for your website as well as other developer-provided assets like graphics, fonts, and icons.
> - Firebase Storage stores files such as images, videos, and audio as well as other user-generated content.

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks for the reply. So when I replaced: compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.2.0' and compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0' with     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.1' it worked. So does that mean it was just my android studio needing more updates for your code snipets to work?

Comment: Also your definitions helped clarify my confusion. So thanks for that also.