# Where to store large amounts of static data Firebase

Tags: firebase

I was wondering where the best place to store a lot of static data in Firebase is. By static data I mean info such as city name, city information, city coordinates. I would only like to store user information in the Real-time Database, because it is more cost effective for me.

Should I create a `json` file and put it in `storage`, or should I host it right in the Firebase Hosting? I will need to access this data quite often. Please Help!

Comment: Storage would give you some control over access to the static data: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/

Comment: If you generate the file yourself, you'll probably want to go with Firebase Hosting as it has a CDN. If users create the files (just never modify them), you should go with Firebase Storage. It doesn't have a CDN, but has an API and is (slightly cheaper). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482907/firebase-differences-between-realtime-database-and-file-storage

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen so would it be possible to store a `json` file in the Hosting?

Comment: Sure. Just try it and report back if you have a problem.