# Load and return an image from Firebase database/storage in React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I've got a Firebase app setup, with an array of items in the Realtime Database. Each item has an `imagePath` node, containing a Firebase Storage URI (eg. gs://bucket/images/stars.jpg).

The array of items is used in a `<ListView/>`, and I need to load an image in each row.

Seen as the images aren't stored directly in a "plain" URL format, I need to use the storage API to get that.

So in my `renderRow(responseItem)` function, I've got the following:

```
<View style={styles.imgWrap}>
    {this.getImage(responseItem.imgPath)}
</View>
```

And that function is the following:

```
getImage(path) {
    FirebaseApp.storage().refFromURL(path).getDownloadURL().then((url) => {

        return (
            <Image
                style={styles.candidateImg}
                source={{uri: url}}/>
        )

    })

}
```

The problem is, nothing's being returned.

If I run a `console.log(url)` above the `return` in `getImage`, it logs the correct URL, that I can open in browser.

Tldr; storage API is getting image URL correctly, but react-native isn't returning the `<Image/>` component.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in async invoking of `getImage()`, try this:

```
<View style={styles.imgWrap}>
    <Image
        style={styles.candidateImg}
        source={this.state.img}/>
</View>


getImage(path) {
    FirebaseApp.storage().refFromURL(path).getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
        this.setState({img: {uri: url}});
    })
}

// and invoke in renderRow
this.getImage(responseItem.imgPath)
```

Of course you should create an array of uri's to handle `<ListView />`

Comment: Aha, so I'd do `this.state.img` as an array, adding each rows image to it, and then get the necessary array item in each row? With something like `source={this.state.img[rowId]}`.