# Can I Save parameters in firebase without using firebase database and read it on my website in js file?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I want to save same values on firebase and read those values in my web app. 
I have my own database (mssql) and I don't want to use firebase database.

For example, I want to save those values on firebase:

actionText = "test"

btnConfirmText = "Aprrove"

btnConfirmColor = "#fffff"

And on my website read those values in javascript

Comment: You can use [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-rest) if you need to do A/B testing of these values.  If this never changes or is always in sync, you can use [Firebase hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/) and just serve as `application/json`.

Comment: @JamesPoag: Firebase Remote Config doesn't have a client-side API for reading the values into the client.

Comment: @tokenaizer: where **do** you want to store these values? Saying "in Firebase, but not in the database" is rather broad. If you're looking for what options there are to store data in Firebase from a web client, then have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482907/firebase-differences-between-realtime-database-and-file-storage

Comment: There is REST API, which I thought is what I linked to??  It should return a json object...

Comment: Elaborating on Frank's comment, for what do you want to use Firebase for? Only for the hosting? For the authentication? For the Cloud Functions? Or maybe for Firestore, which IS one of the NoSQL DBs of the Firebase platform. If you have your own DB (MS SQL, as you explain), what is your aim by using Firebase?

Comment: I think Remote Config will be the right option for me because it's integrate with analytics but i don't know if it support client-side api.