# What's the best way to store static data in firebase

Tags: firebase

I'm writing firebase android app in android studio. I have almost 2000 geo locations and I want them to be marked on map all the time. Firebase databse isn't good idea to store such data because this is static data. So firebase storage, hosting, just some list in code or something different would be the best way?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For static data that you create yourself, I'd use Firebase Hosting. It gives you a simple way to update the data with `firebase deploy`, and comes with a built-in CDN.

For unstructured data that your users create, use Cloud Storage for Firebase.

For structured data that your users create, use Cloud Firestore or the Realtime Database.

Also see: [Firebase : Differences between realtime database and file storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482907/firebase-differences-between-realtime-database-and-file-storage)

Answer (score 0):

For static data, you could use list and [append](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data) all the geo locations with `push()` method.  The `push()` method generates a unique key every time a new child is added to the specified Firebase reference.

By using these auto-generated keys for each new element in the list, several clients can add children to the same location at the same time without write conflicts. The unique key generated by `push()` is based on a timestamp, so list items are automatically ordered chronologically.