# Which firebase service should I use for my android quizzes app

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm currently creating an Android app that is for quizzes and the quizzes' questions are mainly textual but a small amount of them will be audio or images, Which Firebase service should I use to store the data for those questions in addition to linking the users that are signed in the app ***with firebase authentication*** with the quizzes questions' data?

And the admin of the app wants to upload the data himself as CSV, mp3 , jpg regularly from time to time
He has little technical knowledge so the process of uploading should be fairly easy

Many thanks in advance I'm so desperate for a solution

I tried using Firestore but I knew that it's for small file sizes so images and audio can't be there

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37483948?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm currently creating an Android app that is for quizzes and the quizzes' questions are mainly textual but a small amount of them will be audio or images.

For text, I recommend you use either [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) or the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database). Which is best? It's hard to say without knowing the exact queries that you intend to perform. So it depends on the use case of your app. In this case, I recommend you check:

- [Choose a Database: Cloud Firestore or Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore)

When it comes to storing files, the best option that you have is to use [Cloud Storage for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage).

All the above Firebase Products are working hand in hand with the [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth).

Comment: Ok how can the admin upload the quizzes folders given that he has no technical background ? Is there a way to upload folders easily to the firebase?

note: a quiz folder contains csv file for the questions and answers and images/ audio if they exist

Comment: *How can the admin upload the quiz folders given that he has no technical background?* You have to create a mechanism yourself that does that. So you have to write code for that. *Is there a way to upload folders easily to the Firebase?* Yes, if you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).

Answer (score 0):

The first requirement for a Firebase-based quiz app is Firebase Storage. There should be a form for the admin to add questions and multiple options. Additionally, there should be an option to attach files, which can be stored on Firebase Storage. The attachment's URL should then be stored in Firebase Realtime Database, along with other data such as questions and options. In the Realtime Database, you can also store the options selected by users and their scores.

For user login, you can utilize mobile number authentication, which is a trendy approach.